# Ionic 4 nested tabs

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-tabs

I have a 3 tabs on bottom which is the parent tab. It generated through CLI. I need another 2 tabs on top which will be as a child of the second tab. I am using `Ionic 4` latest version. Is there any way I can achieve it. I couldn't find a solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try this: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/segment

Comment: Definitely right @Najamussaqib

Comment: Yes.It did work. Thank you

Comment: @NajamusSaqib ion-segment is useful for toggling between different views while staying on same page, how about when we have to navigate between pages?

Comment: @NaveedAhmed please let me know complete scenario.